# Why -l option in lua interpreter acts strangely?

Tags: lua

> You can execute a sequence of chunks by giving them all as arguments
>   to the stand-alone interpreter, with the -l option. For instance, if
>   you have a file a with a single statement x=1 and another file b with
>   the statement print(x), the command line
>
> ```
> prompt> lua -la -lb
> ```
>
> will run the chunk in a, then the one in b, which will print the
>   expected 1.

The above is from the following link: https://www.lua.org/pil/1.1.html. Yet, when I was trying it out, I got a syntax error.

So, in file a.lua, I have only one line, which is `a=1`. Then in file b.lua, I have also only one line `print("the value of a is:",a)` . Then,

```
:~$ lua -i -la -lb
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
the value of a is:  true
> 
:~$ 

:~$ lua -la -lb
the value of a is:  true
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
>
```

Why did it print out "the value of a is: true"? rather than "the value of a is: 1"?
Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice question!  The option `-lxx` not only executes `xx.lua` but also creates global variable `xx` (the same name as the file) and assigns the value returned by the chunk to this variable.  If no value was returned, then value `true` is used.

Comment: Try `$ lua -i -e 'require"a";require"b"'` to avoid overwriting of variable `a`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Post an answer. It would be weird (or awkward!) for anyone else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are use `a = 1` in your file `a.lua`, unlike in the example where `a.lua` contains `x = 1` and `b.lua` contains `print(x)`.

Using `a` rather then `x` means your using the same `a` variable being written to when `-la` completes, changing it to `true`.

This happens because the option `-l name` is equal to `name = require("name")`. When require completes, on a file that returns no result to it, require will return `true`.

your command `lua -la -lb` would look something like this to lua:

```
a = require("a") --this returning true after it completes
b = require("b") --this printing the value of `a` which will always be `true`
```

Sources:

> [Similar question answered on Lua-Users: command-line -l option issue](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-02/msg00387.html)
>
> [Egor Skriptunoff's Comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716372/why-l-option-in-lua-interpreter-acts-strangely#comment103726242_58716372)